# CakePHP 2. Routing - Domain/Model/Action/ID to Doamain/ID

Tags: routes, cakephp-2.1

Well, I am struggling for 2 hours trying to finding out how this not works. The problem:

The default routing is

```
     Domain      / Model  /  Action  /  ID
```

I like to have

```
     Domain      /   ID
```

http://www.mydoaim.com/Del_Sol

They only thing I got that is close to it is

Right now I have

```
     Domain      / ALIAS  /  ID
```

http://www.mydoaim.com/dr/Del_Sol

Router::connect('/dr/**', array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'app_index', ));

But is not the same, I don't even know if What I´m asking would work because and ID could have the same name of a controller. Also my server is running NGIX

Answer (score 0):

The default routing is:

```
Domain / Controller / Action / Id
```

Your id should not have the same name as a controller since it should be an integer, right?
You should be able to do:

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'app_index', ));
```

The way that routing works is that **it matches the first rule it encounters** in `routes.php`. So, if this `/*` rule matches everything else - just put more precise rules before it.

Again the most important thing is that the first rule matched in `routes.php` has precedence.